# Joining columns with similar names in the same data frame

Tags: r

I am working with plant cover data of several species, some of them with the same genus. Each column of the data set is a species and each row a sampling site. I only need the cover data at the genus level and I would like to sum the columns of those species within the same genus

I have something similar to this but with many more species:

```r
df<-data.frame('Abies.alba'= c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1), 'Acer.opalus'= c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
               'Acer.campestre'= c(1, 0 , 1, 1, 0), 'Pinus.sylvestris'= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
               'Pinus.uncinata'= c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0))
```

And I would like to have something resembling this:

```r
df2<-data.frame('Abies'= c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1), 'Acer'= c(1, 0, 2, 2, 1),
               'Pinus'= c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1))
```

My main problem is that I have a lot of different genus to join. I have thought about transposing the data frame and suming the rows, which I have done before, but I feel like there has to be a better way of doing it.

Comment: `sapply(split.default(df, sub("\\..*", "", names(df))), rowSums)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea via base R is to split the coplumn names and use `grepl` to find the similar ones, i.e.

```
sapply(unique(gsub('\\..*', '', names(df))), function(i)rowSums(df[grepl(i, names(df))]))
#     Abies Acer Pinus
#[1,]     0    1     1
#[2,]     1    0     1
#[3,]     0    2     2
#[4,]     0    2     1
#[5,]     1    1     1
```

Comment: Thanks, this one worked best. The thing is I had to keep the genus in columns and sites in rows because that is the only format that the community ecology analysis functions admit.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reshaping data from wide to long (preferred format in almost every analytical method), then clean columns by period for *genus* and *species* fields. From there run needed sum aggregation.

```
rdf <- reshape(df, varying = list(names(df)), v.names = "value", 
               times = names(df), timevar="species", 
               new.row.names = 1:1E6, direction = "long")

rdf$genus <- gsub("\\..*", "", rdf$species)
rdf$species <- gsub(".*\\.", "", rdf$species)

head(rdf)
#   species value id genus
# 1    alba     0  1 Abies
# 2    alba     1  2 Abies
# 3    alba     0  3 Abies
# 4    alba     0  4 Abies
# 5    alba     1  5 Abies
# 6  opalus     0  1  Acer

aggdf <- aggregate(value ~ genus, rdf, sum)

aggdf
#   genus value
# 1 Abies     2
# 2  Acer     6
# 3 Pinus     6
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/CCRLF27699)

Answer (score 1):

In general I do think it makes more sense to transpose your data as you said.  This will help you take advantage of R's vectorized operations, which work best with "tidy" data (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  This is how I would do it:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 gather(species, count, 2:6) %>%
 mutate(species = str_replace(species, "(?=\\.).+", "")) %>%
 group_by(rowid, species) %>%
 summarise(count = sum(count))

# which gets you

# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   rowid [5]
   rowid species count
   <int> <chr>   <dbl>
 1     1 Abies       0
 2     1 Acer        1
 3     1 Pinus       1
 4     2 Abies       1
 5     2 Acer        0
 6     2 Pinus       1
 7     3 Abies       0
 8     3 Acer        2
 9     3 Pinus       2
10     4 Abies       0
11     4 Acer        2
12     4 Pinus       1
13     5 Abies       1
14     5 Acer        1
15     5 Pinus       1
```

If you then really wanted your genus information in columns you could then add these lines:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 gather(species, count, 2:6) %>%
 mutate(species = str_replace(species, "(?=\\.).+", "")) %>%
 group_by(rowid, species) %>%
 summarise(count = sum(count)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%  
 spread(species, count) %>%
 select(-rowid)
```